# Yang-Mills optical theorem computation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, polarization, yang-mills, s-matrix-theory

In Peskin&Schroeder, chapter 16.3 (page 516) we compute in the context of the optical theorem the quantity
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(i\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{-*}_\mu\epsilon^{+*}_\nu\right)\left(i\mathcal{M}'^{\rho\sigma}\epsilon^+_\rho\epsilon^-_\sigma\right)+\left(i\mathcal{M}^{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{+*}_\mu\epsilon^{-*}_\nu\right)\left(i\mathcal{M}'^{\rho\sigma}\epsilon^-_\rho\epsilon^+_\sigma\right)\right]
$$
which then the authors find to be
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(ig\bar{v}(p_+)\gamma_\mu t^cu(p)\cdot\frac{-i}{(k_1+k_2)^2}\cdot g f^{abc}k_1^\mu\right)\times\left(ig\bar{u}(p')\gamma_\rho t^d v(p_+')\cdot\frac{-i}{(k_1+k_2)^2}\cdot g f^{abc}\left(-k_2^\mu\right)\right)+\left(k_1\leftrightarrow k_2\right)
$$

*I don't mind the second term here, namely $(k_1\leftrightarrow k_2)$. This is not our concern in this question.*

My question is the following. I am able to calculate the first term (the one multiplied with $k_1^\mu$) but wouldn't the second part of the first term be also of the form $(k_2^\mu)$ instead of $(-k_2^\mu)$?

***There is nothing different in the computation of the diagrams that would introduce that negative sign.***

**Some Clarifications**

The first term is the term we get when we compute the 3 diagrams that contribute to the proccess $f\bar{f}\rightarrow gg$ (fermion anti-fermion annihilation to 2 gauge bosons), this is denoted by $\mathcal{M}$. Then $\mathcal{M}'$ denotes the proccess $gg\rightarrow f\bar{f}$ (fermion anti-fermion creation from 2 gauge bosons). Furthermore, the polarisation vectors given are defined as
$$
\epsilon_\mu^+(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}|\vec{k}|}\left(k^0,\vec{k}\right)\;\;\;\;\;\epsilon_\mu^-(k)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}|\vec{k}|}\left(k^0,-\vec{k}\right)
$$