# Typo of P&S' QFT eq.(16.40)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, unitarity, ghosts

First, begin with P&S's QFT eq.(16.39):
$$ \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(i \mathcal{M}^{\mu \nu} \epsilon_\mu^{-*} \epsilon_\nu^{+*}\right)\left(i \mathcal{M}^{\prime \rho \sigma} \epsilon_\rho^{+} \epsilon_\sigma^{-}\right)+\left(i \mathcal{M}^{\mu \nu} \epsilon_\mu^{+*} \epsilon_\nu^{-*}\right)\left(i \mathcal{M}^{\prime \rho \sigma} \epsilon_\rho^{-} \epsilon_\sigma^{+}\right)\right] \tag{16.39}$$

Then, the book put result in (16.40)
$$\begin{aligned}
& \frac{1}{2}\left(i g \bar{v}\left(p_{+}\right) \gamma_\mu t^c u(p) \cdot \frac{-i}{\left(k_1+k_2\right)^2} \cdot\left(-g f^{a b c} k_1^\mu\right)\right) \\
& \quad \times\left(i g \bar{u}\left(p^{\prime}\right) \gamma_\rho t^d v\left(p_{+}^{\prime}\right) \cdot \frac{-i}{\left(k_1+k_2\right)^2} \cdot\left(-g f^{a b d}\left(-k_2\right)^\rho\right)\right)+\left(k_1 \leftrightarrow k_2\right) .
\end{aligned} \tag{16.40}$$

I think there is a typo,
$$\left(k_1 \leftrightarrow k_2\right) \rightarrow \left(k_1 \leftrightarrow -k_2\right) $$
Since the minus sign in $-k_2$ arise from calculation of
$$k_{1\mu} \cdot \text{(3 boson vertex)} $$
And there can't be a term like $-k_1$.

Comment: I have the same question. There is some funny business with that negative sign here which no-one seems to be able to explain.

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/720169/225553

Comment: @twistedmanifold Yeah, we have similar question, maybe the book omit the minus sign!